# Return 2d subset array of 1d integer array in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, subset

I'm not able to store subsets of the array in 2D array.

Need help in recursion part of it.

```
public static int[][] subsets(int input[]) {
    int index=0;
    return help(input , index);
}

private static int[][] help(int []input, int index){
    int n= input.length;

    if(index >= input.length){
        int ans[][]= new int [0][0];
        return ans;
    }

    int samllAns[][] = help(input, index+1);
    int ans[][] = new int[(n*n)][];

    /* unable to get this part*/
    return ans;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and look what your input.length is. Control your input parameters, if they were passed correctly or passed in the way you think they should have been passed.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide one or more example inputs and the outputs they should produce.  Include the output your program _actually_ produces (if any).  (Also, read the Help Center's "[ask]", if you haven't already.)

Comment: What are the rules for filling the 2d array? I could think for example that only the diagonal should be filled: but that may not be the expected output

Comment: sample input : 3  {1, 2 ,3}    output:{(  ), (1),(2),(3) ,(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(1,2,3)}

Comment: Again, [edit] your question to include important details like inputs and outputs.  That information will never be seen down here in the comments.  (Evidence:  I spotted that almost a week after you wrote it.)

Answer (score 0):

here's my answer. Functioning effectively. it will return the output in the form of a 2D array.

```
    public static void PrintSubsets(int[] input, boolean[] ifPrint, int 
             start, int remain){
    if(remain==0)
    {
      for(int i=0; i<ifPrint.length;i++)
        {
        if(ifPrint[i])
        System.out.print(input[i]+" ");   
        }
      System.out.print("\n");
    }
        else if(start+remain>input.length)
        return;

        else
       {
        for(int i = start; i<input.length; i++)
        {
         if(!ifPrint[i])    
          {
          ifPrint[i]=true;
          PrintSubsets(input, ifPrint, i+1, remain-1);
          ifPrint[i]=false;
                 }
               }
             }
`         }
   public static int[][] subsets(int input[]) {
    return subsets(input,0);
   }
   public static int[][] subsets(int input[], int StartIndex) {

    if(StartIndex==input.length)
    {
    return new int[1][0];
    }

    int SmallAns1[][]=subsets(input,StartIndex+1);
    int SmallAns2[][]=subsets(input,StartIndex+1);

    int ans[][]=new int[SmallAns1.length+SmallAns2.length][];
    int l=0;
    for(int i=0;i<SmallAns1.length;i++)
    {
        ans[l]=new int[SmallAns1[i].length + 1];
        ans[l][0] = input[StartIndex];
        for(int j=1;j<=SmallAns1[i].length;j++)
        {
            ans[l][j]=SmallAns1[i][j - 1];
        }
        l++;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<SmallAns2.length;i++)
    {
        ans[l]=new int[SmallAns2[i].length];
        for(int j=0;j<SmallAns2[i].length;j++)
        {
            ans[l][j]=SmallAns2[i][j];
        }
        l++;
    }        

    return ans;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class solution {
    public static int[][] subsets(int input[],int index){
        if(index>=input.length){
            int[][] myAns = new int[1][0];
            return myAns;
        }
        int[][] smallAns = subsets(input,index+1);
        int[][] ans = new int[2*smallAns.length][];
        int k =0;
        int len = smallAns.length;
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            ans[k] = new int[smallAns[i].length];
            for(int j=0;j<smallAns[i].length;j++){
                ans[k][j] = smallAns[i][j];
            }
            k++;
        }
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++){
            ans[k] = new int[smallAns[i].length+1];
            ans[k][0] = input[index];
            for(int j=1;j<=smallAns[i].length;j++){
                ans[k][j] = smallAns[i][j-1];
            }
            k++;
        }
        return ans;
    }
    public static int[][] subsets(int input[]) 
    {
        return subsets(input,0);
    }
}
```